# My int value gets only between 0 and 250 in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an integer called `EpisodeTime` and I can't assign to this more than 250. In the database it's type is int. What's causing it ?

View model:

```
[Display(Name ="Episode Time")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot be null")]
[Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
public int EpisodeTime{ get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Episode Time")]
public string EpisodeTimeStr
{
    get
    {
        return (EpisodeTime/ 60).ToString() +" Minutes"+ " " + (EpisodeTime% 60).ToString()+" Seconds"; 
    }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.BSMaterialTextBoxFor(model => model.EpisodeTime, "Enter episode time as second",colCSS: "col-6", htmlAttributes: new { data_bindrop = "EpisodeTime" , autocomplete = "off" })
```

Service:

```
public ViewModelResponse SaveEpisode(EpisodeViewModel episodeVM)
{
    ViewModelResponse result = new ViewModelResponse(false);
    var repositoryEpisode = GetRepository<NobetCizelgesi>();

    var nobetKisi = repositoryNobet.Queryable()
                                   .Where(w => w.ID == episodeVM.ID && w.PersonID == episodeVM.PersonID)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();

    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

    if (nobetKisi == null)
    {
        NobetCizelgesi cizelge = new NobetCizelgesi();
        cizelge.ID = Guid.NewGuid();              
        cizelge.NobetSure = (byte)nobetVM.NobetSure;      

        repositoryNobet.Insert(cizelge);

        result.Success = repositoryNobet.Save();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How you passing data to database?

Comment: I pass it as byte. What should I do ?

Comment: A byte is a number between 0 and 255. Try an int instead

Comment: It works now when I removed the byte. Int is redundant because it's already int , thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

- Glad that you have cleared the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72009515/my-int-value-gets-only-between-0-and-250-in-mvc).
- Based on your comments posting that as an answer to help the other `community members` who are facing with the same issue.
- Thanks to [vives](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17847724/vives) & [Jonas Høgh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85215/jonas-h%C3%B8gh) for the valuable comments.
- Here in this thread we no need to pass as a `byte`. A byte is a number between 0 and 255.
- `Int` is redundant because it's already int in this case.